# ASP.NET Grid View with merged columns(Headers)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I want to fill data(Data from SQL Database) into Gridview in the following format.
How can I design grid and Fill data into grid?
[image]

Comment: Here is another reference, in addition to the one suggested by Lucky: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Group-Header-Row-Columns-and-display-Multiple-Columns-under-Single-Column.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an OnDataBound event `protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)` and use the `RowSpan` wherever is needed.

Comment: Refer to this URL and manipulate it according to your need, http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Merge-GridView-Cells-or-Columns-in-a-Row-in-ASPNet-using-C-VBNet.aspx